# SAS Enterprise Guide - Export Temporary "WORK" table Into Multiple Worksheets in Same Workbook Based on Criteria

Tags: sas, export-to-excel, enterprise-guide, sysdate

I've searched and searched, but I can't seem to find a solution.

I'm on 8.2 Update 4 (8.2.4.1261) (32-bit).

Can someone help me export a table into an Excel file with multiple sheets?

Example: Table contains a list of USA professional sports teams (with their city/nickname and league they are in). Each tab would be separated by league (NBA, MLB, NFL, NHL, MLS). How would I go about this?

I'd also like to add the current date to the output Excel file name. From what I've read, I can create a variable with the sysdate. Just not sure how to incorporate it in the code.

Answer (score 1):

- Each sheet name is to be based on a group.

  - In SAS we use the `BY` statement to specify the variable(s) that form a group -- in your case, it is the one variable `league`
- The `BY` statement makes special tokens available during output, `#BYVAR<n>` and `#BYVAL<n>`

  - You want the value of the `league` to be important (sheet name) during output so `#BYVAL1`
- `ODS EXCEL` sheet name construction is specified in the `OPTIONS` option.  You can use the `BY` token in the option.

  - You want `ODS EXCEL ... OPTIONS (sheet_name="#BYVAL1") ...;`
- A `BY` statement in output procedures produces an extra line `<BYVAR>=<BYVAL>` which would be *noise* in your Excel output.

  - Prevent the noise with `OPTIONS NOBYLINE;`

Example:

```
ods excel file='output.xlsx' options(sheet_name="#BYVAL1");

options nobyline;

proc print noobs data=sashelp.cars;
  by make;
run;

ods excel close;
```

Produces

[image]

**More**

If you want the `BY` variable to appear in the `PROC PRINT` output use a `VAR _ALL_;` statement, or list the columns wanted explicity.

Adding the `BY` variable to the output will make things easier if you need to import and combine data that was edited in Excel, or if you are making various charts and such.  In reality you might be better of producing a single worksheet with all the data and then using **autofilter** (which is an `ODS EXCEL` option) and Excel pivot tables/charts if you are doing other work in Excel.  (Proc `TABULATE` and `REPORT` can do a very large subset of what pivot tables can do.)

Comment: Thank you for your response. Can you tell me how to point it to a specific folder? How about adding the current date to the end of the file? Running your provided code, I receive this error message "ERROR: Insufficient authorization to access /sasapps/sas_config/Lev4/SASEnt/output.xlsx."

Comment: In the FILE option, place the full path and folder you'd like it to be saved to. Note that the SAS server must have access to this location, so if you're working with EG on a server, you likely cannot save to your desktop. `file = "/folders/myfolders/demo_%sysfunc(date(), yymmddn8).xlsx"`

Comment: My EG is on a server, and I can use the "export" or "export as a step" option. However, that doesn't give me ability to customize the file name like I could by writing a program. I've tried every tutorial I can find, but I just can't seem to get a clear way of doing this. Something that should be so simple is very challenging (for me). Can someone provide me the exact code you would use if you were trying to send a brand new dataset into a brand new Excel file and then put different qualifying data into each tab?

Comment: The Unix path token tilde (~) is your home folder where you login.  You should be able to see your home folder and any sub folder you create in the tree shown in your server connection panel.  So adjusting @Reeza path `file=~/demo_%sysfunc(date(), yymmddn8).xlsx`

Comment: You will have to export it to the server using the approach above and then download the created file. This is a limitation based on how your system is set up, not really a SAS limitation. The other option is to convince your IT team to map a common network drive to your SAS installation that is also available to you on your local machine.